# Chrome extension: Activate and execute background.js on click from popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

As I understand from [Manage Events with Background Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and [Migrate to Event Driven Background Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_migration) background script should be activated when [events](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) triggered.

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, reply) => {

    const json = message.data;
    // some code

    reply({ result: true })
    return true;    
});
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ data: [<ArrayWithData>] },
    function (response) {
        logger.log(response);
    }
);
```

Everything works well, but only in case of active background.

Why background not become active? Can someone explain what is my mistake?
Or **how can I activate and execute background.js on click from popup.js**?

I know that if I change `persistence: true` in **manifest.json** or just remove it, everything will works fine. But I want to keep `persistence false` and trigger background.js when needed.

Comment: The posted code isn't enough to diagnose the problem. Do you rely on global variables in the background script? First, maybe you don't need a background script at all as the popup has the same level of access. Second, make sure you're looking at the correct console: right-click the popup and click "inspect".

Comment: @wOxxOm, From documentation: background script should be activated when events triggered. I call event from popup json and onMessage dont triggered. Which piece of code should also i need to add? By the way, nackground script is in inactive mode, so console.log will not work. The main goal of my post is set background active on event triggered.

Comment: You need to show [MCVE](/help/mcve), otherwise we can only randomly guess. It seems you misunderstood the documentation. The background script runs in a separate page and that hidden page is automatically loaded on a message when persistent is false. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029) how to inspect it. The popup is a separate page too. The background script doesn't run inside the popup (some people load it in popup.html but that's a mistake caused by misunderstanding). Your console.log runs in the popup so it'll be printed in the popup's devtools console.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Sorry maybe I dont undestood you. Cause I already show MCVE. Also I dont have the trouble with console.log. And I know about background is separate page. My question is rather clear. I need to background become active when I sendMessage from popup.js.

Comment: Sadly, it's not an MCVE but I don't want to argue over this. Hopefully someone else will guess right.

Comment: @wOxxOm Only thing to reproduce is just put onMessage to background.js and then sendMessage from popup.js while background.js is in inactive mode. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When I said it's not MCVE, it means the posted code doesn't reproduce the problem so "V" is missing and personally I find it very tiring to argue about such things. The posted code successfully works (logger.log being console.log), assuming everything else that isn't posted in the question is implemented correctly.

Comment: @wOxxOm. Your are totally right. I use logger (from background). But background is inactive, thats why sendMessage was never called. Thank you very much. I need to be more careful

Comment: Yeah, consider using chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(bg => bg.console.log('foo'))

Answer (score 4):

You missed [this part in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_migration#backgroundFunctions) that explains how a background script should be activated from `popup.js`. After retrieving the background page object, you just need to call any function or even access a field.

I always put this at the top of my `popup.js`:

```
// Initialize background page
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {
  console = backgroundPage.console;
})
```

That way I can also view console logs from the popup together with logs from the background view